# How to test ConfigurtionProperties for immutable records?

Tags: java, spring-boot, record, configurationproperties

I have records taking values from configuration properties:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "car")
public record CarConfig(Type type) {
    public record Type() {}
}
```

I cannot put there `@Configuration` annotation cause as it is a record, it is immutable.
Now - I would like to test it and it's not a problem when I will use `@SpringBootTest` with all context but I prefer to not do this.

Instead of this I created something like that:

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = CarConfig.class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class CarConfigTest {

    @Autowired
    private CarConfig carConfig;

    @Test
    void shouldReadConfigValues() {
       // some assertions
    }
```

I'm getting an error that it cannot autowire carConfig.class and it make sense as CarConfig is not Spring annotated class.

So my question is - is it possible to test CarConfig without @SpringBootTest annotation? If yes, what should I use?